# Unable to store values in an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Sometime this code works and sometimes it does not. I wish to store the values counted in the array and then `Sum` them. However it is not working. Please excuse my code.

```
Dim PaintWWArray() As Variant
Dim PHoursCnt As Long
Dim PaintWWCnt As Long

Set srchRng = ActiveSheet.Range(rangeString)
Set rngfindValue = srchRng.Find(what:="AD PAINTING W/W", Lookat:=xlPart)

'Find all the Tasks and Hours
If Not rngfindValue Is Nothing Then
   rngFirstAddress = rngfindValue.Address
    Do
        PaintWWCnt = PaintWWCnt + 1
        PHoursCnt = rngfindValue.Offset(0, 4).Value

         ReDim Preserve PaintWWArray(PHoursCnt)
         PaintWWArray(PHoursCnt) = PHoursCnt

         Set rngfindValue = srchRng.FindNext(rngfindValue)

    Loop Until rngfindValue Is Nothing Or rngfindValue.Address = rngFirstAddress

     PHoursCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(PaintWWArray)

      Worksheets("Weekly Report Data").Range("C6").Value = PaintWWCnt
      Worksheets("Weekly Report Data").Range("D6").Value = PHoursCnt

     Debug.Print PHoursCnt
End If
```

Where have I gone wrong? Thank you.

By *Not working* I mean: It does not store the PHoursCnt in the array, the array is empty but for the last counted.

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: Sure, basically the array is 'empty' apart from the 'last' added.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve PaintWWArray(PHoursCnt)` is `PHoursCnt` correct here?  Seems like you might have intended to use `PaintWWCnt`

Comment: The PaintWWCnt is 'adding' on each pass to get the number of how many times it appears, the PHoursCnt is 'meant' to be adding a number from .Offset(0, 4) on each pass into the array.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think you nailed it, but then it seems odd that it would be described as an intermittent error.

Comment: I get you meant to add PHoursCnt to the array, but I didn't think you also meant to resize the array using that value....

Comment: I don't know how large it will get, is there a better way of doing this, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: You need to resize the array to add one more item.  `PaintWWCnt = PaintWWCnt + 1` adds one to the variable that holds the number of items in the array, hence `ReDim Preserve PaintWWArray(PaintWWCnt)` increases the size of the array by one. On the other hand `ReDim Preserve PaintWWArray(PHoursCnt)` increases the array by a random amount (or perhaps even makes it smaller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resizing the array using the wrong value:

```
If Not rngfindValue Is Nothing Then
   rngFirstAddress = rngfindValue.Address
    Do
        PaintWWCnt = PaintWWCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve PaintWWArray(PaintWWCnt) '<<<<<< not PHoursCnt

        PHoursCnt = rngfindValue.Offset(0, 4).Value
        PaintWWArray(PHoursCnt) = PHoursCnt

        Set rngfindValue = srchRng.FindNext(rngfindValue)

    Loop Until rngfindValue Is Nothing Or rngfindValue.Address = rngFirstAddress
```

Comment: OH! yes I was sizing it according to the value and not how many iterations there were...is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that's the problem

Comment: Thank you! Accepted!